# How can I call a function when the user drop the slider with swiftUI?

Tags: slider, swiftui

I want to drag a slider and when it is dropped, it calls a function, but when I use DragGesture my slider does not work any more.

I have read the Apple documentation, but I couldn't find out how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `onEditingChanged` closure parameter. It receives a Bool set to true when the change begins and false when the change ends.

```
Slider(value: $value, in: 0...200, step: 10, onEditingChanged: { bool in
  print("\(bool)")
})
```